# Create installer package with pdf license using productbuild

Tags: macos, productbuild

I'm using productbuild command line tool on mac to create pkg installer. I need to provide an EULA in my package, so I've modified distribution.xml to include license:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<installer-gui-script minSpecVersion="1">
    <license file="EULA.pdf" />
    ...
</installer-gui-script>
```

But it looks like pdf is not recognizeable by productbuild, license step shows pdf file content in plain text. I've tried to specify mime-type attribute, but the result is the same. After some googling, I've found that most people using either rtf or html license files.

Are supported file formats/UTI/MIME types documented somewhere? The only documentation I was able to find is https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/DistributionDefinitionRef/Chapters/Distribution_XML_Ref.html , but it doesn't say anything about supported formats.

More important question - can I somehow create an installer package with pdf license?

Comment: Hi Borys, are you able to install using pkg? I have a question as it never installs in Application/

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Yes, pkg works for me, but my app is not installed in the /Applications folder

Comment: Then how you say it works? Are you installing it somewhere else? If you could help me on this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54112620/the-pkg-created-using-productbuild-is-not-getting-installed-on-applications