# The pkg created using productbuild is not getting installed on Applications/

Tags: macos, visual-studio, package, productbuild

In Mac OSX when I create a package using `productbuild` and it creates, as you can see below how it is used, the target is given `/Applications`. But it never installs at that location. I tried with other paths as well for no luck.

```
_CreateInstaller:
  Creating installer package

  /usr/bin/productbuild --component /Users/anoopvaidya/Documents/Projects/DesktopClient/MyApp.app /Applications /Users/anoopvaidya/Documents/Projects/DesktopClient/MyApp.pkg 

Done Building Project "/Users/anoopvaidya/Documents/Projects/DesktopClient/MyApp.Mac.csproj" (default targets).
Done Building Project "/Users/anoopvaidya/Documents/Projects/DesktopClient/MyApp.Mac.sln" (Build target(s)).

Build succeeded.
```

Guide me to fix this?

Comment: After spending a day, I tried by removing the `.app` and then run the pkg and it installed. But is there a way to make it run irrespective of `.app` existing on the disk?